# I need to format the result of my join between two dataframes where the other dataframe has more than one valid value for that index key

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, join, formatting

I have two dataframes that I am joining on the index key ['UWI']. I use the following code to join them successfully and then write it to a CSV file to look at the result.

```
joinedDF = df.join(df1.set_index('New_UWI'), on='New_UWI')
joinedDF.to_csv(r'Joined_Water_Analysis_WithLithium.csv', index=False)
```

Code works great and one dataframe is created that shows the UWI and its info from the df1 dataframe has been joined correctly to the same UWI in the calling dataframe df. BUT when reviewing the CSV file I realized that if there is more than one record in df1 for a particular [UWI] the Join is forced to replicate that same [UWI] df record in joinedDF. So for example, if df had two rows of valid data for UWI Well 1:

| df UWI | Formation | Top sample depth | Bottom sample Depth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2300 | 2307 |
| Well 1 | Lower Cretaceous | 750 | 757 |

And df1 had two rows of data for that same UWI Well 1:

| df1 UWI | Formation | Top sample depth | Bottom sample depth | Lithium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Well 1 | Cretaceous | 745 | 759 | 8.5 |
| Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2305 | 2308 | 71 |

The JoinedDF will have four rows. The join needs to attach to each Well 1 in df, the two records from df1 Well 1. The resultant JoinedDF is hard for one to scan and determine which Lithium value should go to which Well 1 row in df. It gets worse when there are ten unique records for Well 1 in df and in df1 there are 2 unique records. The result is 20 rows to match which Lithium sample should go with the appropriate record for Well 1.

| df UWI | Formation | Top sample depth | Bottom sample Depth | df1 UWI | Formation | Top sample depth | Bottom sample depth | Lithium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2300 | 2307 | Well 1 | Cretaceous | 745 | 759 | 8.5 |
| Well 1 | Lower Cretaceous | 750 | 757 | Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2305 | 2308 | 71 |
| Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2300 | 2307 | Well 1 | Cretaceous | 745 | 759 | 8.5 |
| Well 1 | Lower Cretaceous | 750 | 757 | Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2305 | 2308 | 71 |

I would prefer if the Join would only show the two original rows for df Well 1 and not replicate the df cell values in the additional rows. In the CSV file I am manually deleting the replicate values in the cells for Well 1 df so the result looks more like below. But is there a way to make Join do this formatting for me because this is a long and tiring manual process otherwise?

| df UWI | Formation | Top sample depth | Bottom sample Depth | df1 UWI | Formation | Top sample depth | Bottom sample depth | Lithium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2300 | 2307 | Well 1 | Cretaceous | 745 | 759 | 8.5 |
| Well 1 | Lower Cretaceous | 750 | 757 | Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2305 | 2308 | 71 |
|  |  |  |  | Well 1 | Cretaceous | 745 | 759 | 8.5 |
|  |  |  |  | Well 1 | Upper Devonian | 2305 | 2308 | 71 |

To make this example short I am only showing that in both Dataframes there are several common columns such as Formation, Top Interval, Bottom Interval, KB elev etc that help us determine which row in df Well 1 should be matched with the unique Lithium value from df1 Well 1.

Answer (score 0):

```py
joinedDF = df.join(df1.set_index('New_UWI'), on='New_UWI')
joinedDF = joinedDF.drop_duplicates()
```

Or simply

```py
joinedDF = df.join(df1.set_index('New_UWI'), on='New_UWI').drop_duplicates()
```

Please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Hi Steele, It did not work. It dropped some but not others, and in some cases it did not drop enough. I cannot find a pattern in it. Just to clarify, in my final CSV example above I can see that the calling dataframe only had two records -the blank cells show me that. The other dataframe that was being joined also had two records and the join has created two extra rows only for the data in this other frame.  My join is working. I am hoping to make the join display the result as I have drafted here. Failing that is there a way to make a Join order? ie Primary key, secondary key, tertiary key?

Comment: I added more to my tables and hopefully clarified the issue better with more explanatory text. Although the more I look at this issue I am pretty sure the Join cannot create a dataframe with empty cells as I have shown in my preferred view. So the question really is . Is there a method for joining where I can specify UWI prime to join on then use interval then use formation? I am hoping this would create a joined dataframe that is far easier for a human to scan an confirm which Lithium value from df1 should be assigned to the test for that well in df.